# How to fire an error when overriding Backbone's the "parse" method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to throw an error when the server response I receive within the `parse()` method is not valid.

I tried setting the `error` key in the options parameter to `false` or call the `options.xhr.error(this, resp, options);` method within my overidden `parse()` method of my model, but none of them causing the `error` callback of the `fetch()` method to trigger.

Any clue?

Here the actual example:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({

  parse: function parse(resp, options){

    if(resp && resp.meta.success){
      return resp.response;
    }else{
      //Throw an error which cause the "error" callback of the fetch method to get triggered
    }
  }
an});
```

Comment: Seems like you'd be better to override `sync` since it is generally assumed that by the time `parse` runs, you know that the request succeeded.

Comment: The error callback will only be called if your response is a 400 level or 500 level HTTP Code response.  If your response is a 200 or 300 level HTTP Code response, then the success callback will be run.  How are you determining if the response was an "error"?

Comment: Throwing a fetch error is probably not the right thing as the data has fetched but the data itself is invalid (the error event happens when jQuery ajax's error callback happens). You could still trigger your own error with this.trigger like `this.trigger('parseError', ..)`

Comment: hm, thanks for the feedback so far. Overwriting `sync` is not really an option, after looking how big method is.

I agree about the HTTP Code suggestion, but sometimes if you use a 3rd party API this is not in your control.

The custom event idea is nice, but I was more looking for an more standard way to still be consistent with the `success` and `error` callback for fetch

Comment: I could trigger the `error` callback of the `fetch()` method by calling `options.error();` within the `parse()` method. But the success callback is still firing.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: How would you do it with overriding the `sync()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override the sync function to trigger the error callback if the response has an error, or call the default success handler with the main response:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  sync: function(method, model, options){
    var error = options.error;
    var success = options.success;
    options.success = function(resp){
      if (resp && resp.meta.success){
        success(resp.response);
      } else{
        error(resp.response);
      }
    };

    return MyModel.__super__.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
  }
});
```